# filter the records using loadash angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
var arr = Array [ Object, Object ]

into arr {
  "name" : "xyz",
  "age" : "22",
  "sports" : Array[
{
   id:1,
   name : "xyz",
},
{
   id:2,
   name : "yyy",
},
]
}

var obj = Object { name: "JXZ", id :1};

var response = _.filter(arr, function(user) {
                        return user.sports.id === obj.id;
                      });
```

filter the record that match with obj's id from arr's sports.id return array object.
I'm suppose to put loop but i guess that not right solution if please

Comment: Use this `return user.sports.id === obj.id && user.sports.name === obj.name;`, if you want to filter on both of the values. In case you want to filter on `id` field, then your current code is fine.

Comment: Try this : `_.filter(arr, ['id', obj.id])`;

Comment: tried does not work

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below code.

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
        $scope.arr = Array [ Object, Object ];

        $scope.arr = {
            "name" : "xyz",
            "age" : "22",
            "sports" : [
              {
                  id:1,
                  name : "xyz",
              },
              {
                  id:2,
                  name : "yyy",
              }
            ]
        }

        var obj =  { name: "JXZ", id :1};

        var filteredSports = _.filter($scope.arr.sports, function (sport) {
            return sport.id == obj.id;
        })

        $scope.arr.sports = filteredSports;
        console.log($scope.arr);
    })        
</script>
```

Comment: //because arr is array and index of 0 is one object and index of 1 is other object that cause it does not work